# Grunt fails because of containing ".js" in source's folder name

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have a problem with using grunt. I've configured the uglify task like this:

```
uglify: {
    my_targets: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'build/dev/Assets/JavaScript',
            src: '**/*.js',
            dest: 'build/dist/Assets/JavaScript'
        }]
    }
}
```

Basically this is working perfect... until it reaches this folder:
**vendor/conditioner.js/** conditioner.js

Grunt thinks that **vendor/conditioner.js** is a file (because it matches my src pattern) and tries to load the file, which of course ends in this error:

```
{ [Error: Unable to read "build/dev/Assets/JavaScript/vendor/conditioner.js" file (Error code: EISDIR).]
  origError: { [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] errno: -4068, code: 'EISDIR', syscall: 'read' } }
```

I have no clue, how to tell grunt to ignore the folder (which ends with ".js") and hope you can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to write a custom filter. In the [documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files) for the files object, it is specified that a filter can be a "valid [fs.Stats method name](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats)". The `isFile` method already exists. We just need to set the name of this filter in our files object:

```
files: [{
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'build/dev/Assets/JavaScript',
    src: '**/*.js',
    dest: 'build/dist/Assets/JavaScript',
    filter: 'isFile'
}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I was on this page, but for any reason I missed the filter option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [custom filter function](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function):

```
uglify: {
    my_targets: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'build/dev/Assets/JavaScript',
            src: '**/*.js',
            dest: 'build/dist/Assets/JavaScript',
            filter: function(filepath) {
                return filepath.indexOf('conditioner.js') > -1 ? false : true;
            }
        }]
    }
}
```